# Trying to use jQuery .post() to redirect user after form POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

log_and_redirect.html

```
   <HTML>
        <HEAD>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                      $('myLoginForm').submit(function(){
                        $.post('<website_to_log_into>', function() {
                          window.location = 'http://google.com';
                        });
                        return false;
                      });
                  });
            </script>
        </HEAD>

        <BODY>
            <FORM NAME="myLoginForm" METHOD="POST" ACTION="<website_to_log_into>">
                <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="username" VALUE="myUsername">
                <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="password" VALUE="myPassw@rd">
            </FORM>
        </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

I'm trying to use the jQuery `.post()` to submit the form to `<website_to_log_into>` with the username and password, and then redirect the user to Google (while still keeping them logged in). I tried running this HTML (with the `<website_to_log_into>` field filled in properly), but it doesn't seem to work. When I click on `log_and_redirect.html`, the browser window is completely blank. I'm fairly new to javascript and jQuery, so I was just wondering if there's anything wrong that I'm doing here and how I can correct it.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is wrong. `$('myLoginForm')` matches an element whose tag is `myLoginForm`, e.g. `<myLoginForm ...>`. To match the `name` attribute, you have to use an attribute selector. Also, you need to provide the parameters to post.

```
$('form[name=myLoginForm]').submit(function() {
    $.post('<website>', $(this).serialize(), function() {
        window.location = 'http://google.com';
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: If I try this it shows "file:///<...>" in the address bar with <...> being the directory where the html file is.

Comment: did you change  `<website>` to a valid url ?

Comment: Are you using a server? If you're posting to a script, you have to use a server.

Comment: Is the web site you're logging into in the same domain as your HTML file? You can't use AJAX across domains, and if your HTML is from a file instead of a server, and website URL will be another domain.

Comment: What I'm the website I'm logging into is, say, Facebook, for example?

Comment: You can't use AJAX across domains. You need to use a proxy script on your own server to do this.

Comment: Facebook probably has an OAuth2.0 service for logging in from other sites. You should check that out.

Comment: The website is not necessarily Facebook, I was just using it as an example. The form works fine logging me in If I just use javascript with document.loginForm.submit(); Is there a way to redirect the user to a site like Google doing this, then?

Comment: There are different rules for form submission and AJAX. Forms are allowed to cross domains, AJAX isn't.

Comment: If you do ordinary form submission, you don't have control over what happens after it's submitted (that's part of the reason why the rules are different). You can't redirect somewhere else, you just load what the server sends back. You can do what you want using a proxy script on your own server, download [Simple PHP Proxy](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/)